# Mapping Keyboard to different pictures

Tags: keyboard, images, hebrew

I modified the Windows Hebrew keyboard to place the Hebrew vowels in place of the number keys in the base state for easier use. (Standard access is through CAPLOCK+SHIFT+number).  When you type a letter and then a vowel, it places the vowel correctly -- usually under the letter.

If you type a vowel after a space, it will create a dotted-line circle with the vowel, the circle being a sort of place-holder for the letter than should have been typed first.  On the on-screen keyboard, the image of the vowel is with that circle since the "picture" associated with the key is the vowel alone with no letter.

Unfortunately, the vowel's image on the on-screen keyboard button is very small to leave room for the circle.

Is there a way to leave the functionality of the key mapping the same but change the image sent to the on-screen keyboard so that it will show just the vowel?  There must be since the DavkaWriter on-screen keyboard does exactly that.

Comment: I am unsure of how to do what you are looking for in windows, but the fact that it can be done in DavkaWriter is not a proof to anything, it could just mean they did it all themselves, in their program. What you should maybe look into is an autohotkey script that will know if you hit a letter first. If not, it will place the vowel as a unicode character, and then when you place a letter, it will replace the vowel that it placed as if it was a letter, and replace it with the correct letter + vowel combo.